# Showing that $f(x)^3 + g(x)^3 + h(x)^3 - 3f(x)g(x)h(x) = 1$ for functions $f$, $g$, and $h$ defined by certain power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm having trouble with this question, I have found the interval of convergence of $h(x)$ to be $(-\infty, \infty)$, but I don't know how to use that for the question as well as the hint. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

> If $$f(x) =\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!},\qquad g(x) =\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!},\qquad h(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{3n+2}}{(3n+2)!}$$ show that 
>   $$f(x)^3 + g(x)^3 + h(x)^3 - 3f(x)g(x)h(x) = 1.$$
>   **Hint:** show that $h'(x) = g(x)$.

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to prove the hint? Once you have the hint, you can prove something similar for $g'$ and for $f'$, and then you can differentiate the left side of the equation you're asked to prove, and see what happens.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: No I can prove the hint, I just need help with the "show that" part and thanks for the edit!

Comment: Thank you! I got it now! Just didn't know what to do with the derivatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f'(x) = h(x)$, $g'(x)=f(x)$, and $h'(x)=g(x)$.  Then consider

$$\frac{d}{dx} [f^3 + g^3 + h^3 - 3 f g h]$$

and show that it is zero using the above derivatives.  Viz.,

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx} [f^3 + g^3 + h^3 - 3 f g h] &= 3 f^2 f'+3 g^2 g'+3 h^2 h' - 3 f'gh-3 f g'h - 3 f g h'\\ &= 3 f^2 h+3 g^2 f + 3 h^2 g - 3 f'gh-3 f g'h - 3 f g h'\\ &= 0  \\\end{align}$$

Also note that $f(0)=1$, $g(0)=0$, and $h(0)=0$.  Thus the integration constant of the above equation is 1, and

$$f^3(x) + g^3(x) + h^3(x) - 3 f(x) g(x) h(x)=1$$

Comment: Aren't we trying to show that it is equal to 1 though?

Comment: Yep.  See the rest of the post (sorry it was fragmented).

Comment: No worries, and thank you! It makes sense! I just didn't know what to do when I had the derivatives!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $h'=g$ and $g'=f$ and $f'=h$, now consider $$(fgh)'=f(g'h+gh')+f'gh$$ $$=fg'h+fgh'+f'gh$$ $$=f^2h+fg^2+gh^2$$ whcih implies that $$fgh=\int f^2h+fg^2+gh^2$$$$=\frac{f^3}{3}+\frac{g^3}{3}+\frac{h^3}{3}+c$$ which implies that $$f^3(x)+g^3(x)+h^3(x)-3f(x)g(x)h(x)=c$$ for all  $x\in \mathbb R$, substitute x=0 to get that c=1 and hence you get the result.